# Get dynamic html table using selenium & parse it using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, selenium, webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content of a HTML table generated dynamically by JavaScript in a webpage & parse it using  BeautifulSoup to use certain values from the table.

Since the content is generated by JavaScript it's not available in source (`driver.page_source`).

Is there any other way to obtain the content and use it? It's table containing list of tasks, I need to parse the table and identify whether specific task I'm searching for is available.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Julian, i'd rather check my "Net" tab in Firebug (or similar tool in other browsers) and get the data like this. If the data is JSON, just use `json.loads()`, if it's html, you can parse it using BS or any other lib as you say. Maybe you would like to try my [dummy lib](https://github.com/starenka/emery), which simplifies this and returns tables as tablib objects, which you can get as csv, excel, json etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to figure out what HTTP requests the Javascript is making, and make the same ones in your Python code. You can do this by using your favorite browser's development tools, or wireshark if forced.